# which answer is correct about a two dimensional array of characters

Tags: arrays, data-structures

Which answer is correct about a two-dimensional array and why?

A two-dimensional array of characters can contain:

- Strings of same length
- Strings of different lengths
- Uninitialized elements
- All of these

Comment: Can you reformat your code in list format like option a) is this, and so on.

Comment: A two-dimensional array of characters can contain:

(a) strings of the same length
(b) strings of different lengths
(c) uninitialized elements
(d) All of these

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this question could be answered as follows, let's take a 2D array `abc[4][4]`.

a) Strings of the same length, let's say I fill this array with as

```
a b c d 
h e l l 
s e l l
t u v w
```

Now, this contains strings with the same length.

b) Strings of different length, let's say I filled this array as follows

```
a b c  
h e l l 
b y e
t o
```

This is all possible for 2 arrays.

c) uninitialised elements.

As you can see in b) part some places are left, which is not an issue for the 2D array.

d) Hence all of them are correct about 2D array.

This might help you!